# How access tokens look like

Tags: sonos

Just a quick question. I am following the Sonos Authorization API to create the authorization code and the token. When I get the token from the api, it looks different than what is says on the documentation. On the documentation it looks like the following:

d37cca67-d509-4c04-9df4-49f8c6f0004b

my access token looks like the following:

rYoF8c9LGgIBNFCK0GzurfjP70ux.

Am I missing a step between getting the access token and the create authorization code?

Comment: I figured it out, it doesn't matter to that end. The issue I had was due to missing another header when I send an HTTP get request